# Collection View not returning cells (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Ok so I've added a UICollectionView inside a UIView and added an item, but I can't seem to figure out why the item is not showing in the collection view. Here's what I have so far:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView!.delegate = self
    self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: "banana.png")
    cell.itemName.text = "banana testing"
    return cell
}
```

I can get the collection view background to change colours but for some reason it doesn't populate the items inside the collection view. Any tip would be appreciated. I've even called the reload function but still no difference:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: Make sure your image name is correct.

Comment: Where did you call reload? In viewDidLoad?

Comment: For debugging try to colour code the collectionView cell's View.

Comment: @HAS yeah I called it in viewDidLoad just to try it out, but it has no effect. It was a long shot.

Comment: @Xcoder the image name is correct. If the problem was the image, then it should at least show the "banana testing" text.

Comment: @PavankumarC I tried `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue` but still no luck. The problem is that the cells don't populate. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is the cellForItemAt indexpath method getting called?? If yes then check with the height and width of the cell

Comment: @PavankumarC That's a good point. I added `return 10` in `numberOfItemsInSection`. I also added `print("this is the index: " , indexPath.row)` in `cellForItemAt indexPath` and I found out that it doesn't get called. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check with your IBOutlet .... After doing delegate and datasource print collectionview and see if it’s printing nil or some value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer a while ago and I thought it's best if I posted the answer. There was nothing wrong with my code or any of my connections in the storyboard. All I had to do was to go in the attributes inspector and under Collection View, change layout from `Custom` to `Flow`.

I think the older versions of Xcode automatically set the layout to `Flow`, but it seems that the default is `Custom` now. I just had to pay a bit more attention to the details.

Comment: Correct answer, I was having the same issue. this helped. Thanks a lot.